# How does boost::optional<> handle local variables?

Tags: c++, boost, scope, global-variables

Consider a piece of code like this:

```
struct B {
    int c;
    B() {
        c = 20;
    }
};
struct A {
    boost::optional<B> m_b;
    void f() {
        B b; 
        this->m_b = b;
    }
};

int main(void) {
    A a;
    a.f();
    cout << a.m_b->c << endl;
}
```

Apparently, `a.m_b` still validly exists, after assigning a local variable `b` to `m_b`.

This kind of confuses me, because I thought assigning an object to `boost::optional<>` was just assigning the address that points to the object. Since in my example that object is `b`, which is a local variable, its address should be invalid after function `f()` is done.

Then why is `a.m_b` still alive? It should be pointing to an invalid address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`boost::optional`'s `operator=` will call `B`'s copy constructor. If you insert this into your `struct B` you can set a breakpoint on it to see what's going on:

```
B(B const& other)
{
}
```

Boost uses a placement new in its implementation, maybe this is what confuses you?

Comment: Ah I see. Didn't know it makes a copy. Thanks!